# Is there any particular difficulty in replacing Ignition coils in a BMW 528i?

Tags: bmw, ignition

My mechanic tells me that he has to replace the 6 ignition coils in my 1998 BMW 528i - he wants $800 to do it.  I can get new coils online for about $30 each, and it *seems* to me that I could put them in myself within an hour.  Am I unaware of some kind of special tuning, knowledge, or tools that would be required, or can I venture into this apparently simple DIY project without worry?

Also, OEM coils replacements are $70, which is still only $420 - so the additional $380 is what has me wondering.

Comment: 380 for install, setup and testing by a BMW garage? Seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Anything under a grand always feels reasonable, lol...just wondering if this is something I could do to save the 500 so that I can afford his christmas bonus!

Comment: Why does he want to replace all of them? Doesn't seem likely that all 6 are bad. What symptoms are you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you have an E39 with an M54 engine, it is as easy as:

1. Unplugging Battery
2. Unplug cable, and possibly unscrew rail
3. Unscrew each coil pack, and replace
4. Reconnect all items, and test drive

Not a very hard job, as all the packs are exposed once you remove the cover.

Comment: The 1998 apparently has the M52 engine: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMW_M52#M52B28

Comment: Have done the plugs, and simple stuff....it looked easy enough, but I just didn't know if there was some magic with new ones...thanks you good people! :)